# User input in python I've tried to research it but most of it doesn't work

Tags: python

Ive had alot of trouble with user input im trying to write a program were the user has to input yes or no but all its printing is the input yes then the print statement and then no then the print statement heres the code ive been using   im using python

```py
val1 = input("yes")
st1 = print("yay")

val2 = input("no")
st2 = print("cool")

if input(val1):
    print(st1)
elif input(val2):
    print(st2)
```

Comment: Read any basic tutorial on how `input()` and `print()` work.

Comment: The `input` function in python requests user input. The parameter that you are passing is the prompt for that input. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: ive tried that @MarkTolonen

Comment: It's really unclear what you're expecting the output to be. Can you [edit] your question to show what you expect, and describe how it's different that your actual output?

Comment: What tutorial shows `print()` returning a value?  And `input`'s parameter is the prompt to print asking for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ding it wrong.
This is how you hould do it. Although you should use a dictionary to map inputs and outputs

```
val1 = "yes"
st1 = "yay"
val2 = "no"
st2 = "cool"

in_txt = input()
if in_txt == val1:
    print(st1)
elif in_txt == val2:
    print(st2)
```

However if you want to have a lot of cases for input/putput do something like

```
responses = {
    "yes": "yay",
    "no": "cool"
}

in_txt = input()
if in_txt in responses.keys():
    print(responses[in_txt])
else:
    print("Unknown input")
```

Comment: why stack overflow so mean they wont even let me post another question cause I didn't know how to do this

Comment: you can surely post another question. Make sure to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. By the way, if an answer solves your problem, could you mark is as solved?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are trying to evaluate user input, not print it.

So the code should be:

```
    val1 = input()
    if val1 == "yes":
        print("yay")
    
    val2 = input()
    if val2 == "no":
        print("cool")
```

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki's answer could be also fitting, depending on what you really want. They achieve slightly different things. He is asking the user for one input and printing depending on the value. I ask for two inputs and decide whether or not to print on two instances.#

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you might think:

```
response_dict = {'yes': 'yay', 'no': 'cool'}
inval = input('Please enter yes or no: ')
print(response_dict.get(inval, "I don't know what you mean"))
```